# How to input command to Ubuntu bash from Matlab?

Tags: matlab, command-prompt, ubuntu-18.04

I have this question when using windows 10. I am trying to do the process in MATLAB previously did directly in Ubuntu bash. (This can integrate the process in Ubuntu with other process runs in Matlab). I've found adding `!` in front of every command makes MATLAB run as command prompt.

Then here is what I have tried:

First, `! ubuntu1804.exe` this start the ubuntu bash. Then I what to cd a path. However, normally I input

`cd VolumeCollisionSolverFork` directly into ubuntu bash.

Now I've tried `! cd ~/VolumeCollisionSolverFork`. It exits with an error:

`-bash: line 1: cd: $'/home/MyAccountName/VolumeCollisionSolverFork\r': Not a directory`. Looks like there is an extra `\r` at the end. Can anyone help me cd the right path? Or is there any other way can run Ubuntu from Matlab easier? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems like `\r` is the carriage return character. It is probably inserted instead of you pressing "Enter".

Have you tried using the `system` command?

```matlab
system("cd ~/VolumeCollisionSolverFork")
```